# why is my png img of QR not displaying in php

Tags: php, xampp, qr-code

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate() in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php(32): QRimage::image(Array, 5, 4) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\libs\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(494): QRimage::png(Array, 'temp/184011_inf...', 5, 4, false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\libs\phpqrcode\qrencode.php(286): QRencode->encodePNG('\tRoll no: 18401...', 'temp/184011_inf...', false) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\index.php(57): QRcode::png('\tRoll no: 18401...', 'temp/184011_inf...', 0, 5) #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\the_base\qr\libs\phpqrcode\qrimage.php on line 74`

This is the error I am getting since I've updated my XAMPP. This same code has worked perfectly with an older version of xampp but when I  updated it, the code suddenly started to give this error
I am trying to create a QR code in png format and make it downloadable
I did a little research about it, it said that the GD lib was missing in the PHP but all the steps shown to fix it were of LINUX OS, I am currently using Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. go to php.ini file `xampp/php/php.ini`
2. search for `;extension=gd` and `;extension=gd2`
3. remove the `;` from both lines, then restart the server

Comment: I couldn't find the `;extension=gd2` line in the file but uncommenting only the `;extension=gd` line made it work.

Comment: Life saver. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

there might be two cases:
1.gd installed and disabled
2. gd not installed and disabled

for first case:
on XAMPP server click on Apache config -> php.ini
1.open this file in notepad
2. search for ;extension=gd or ;extension=gd2
3. remove the colon ; ( just extension=gd)
4. save it .

for second case gd not installed:
check it through:
(on browser) localhost/dashboard
xampp dashboard opens up, on upper left go to phpinfo()
search for gd section if not present then follow down:
1.open folder : xampp/php/ext
2. then find and Copy php_gd.dll and paste it into the following folder
3.C:\Windows\System32
4. paste php_gd.dll here.
5. restart xampp server and run.

for better explanation:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-php-gd-in-windows/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the **php_gd2** extension isn't enabled.

you have to enable it in php.ini. To do this, simply open php.ini and uncomment (remove the leading ;) the following line:

```
extension=php_gd2.dll
```

Comment: I couldn't find `extension=php_gd2.dll` in the php.ini, but uncommenting `extension=gd` worked like a charm